# I can't filter by date in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I cannot filter by date on SQL, did I do wrong syntax?

But if I use >= operator, it did the job. When I wanted to find the id that was created_at at a specific date, in this case, is '2021-03-01', nothing appears.

The expected output is Id that created at that specific date.

Preview of the data

[image: Here]

and here is my syntax

```
select 
    id 
from job_post
where 
    created_at = '2021-03-01';
```

Comment: @Mat do you mean adding the 'Date' so I make it like:

date('2021-03-01') ?

Comment: Change the format of the datetimes you store in the table to the ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` This is the only valid text datetime format for SQLite. Then you can use date functions of SQLite like `date()` to solve your problem: `where date(created_at) = '2021-03-01';`

Comment: i will try this, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Created_at` is of datetime type when you are comparing this column with a date value it's returning false.

You need to cast datetime to date format to compare with `=` operator.

Instead of `Created_at` use `date(Created_at)`. It will only select the date part of the value which you will be able to compare with any date value with `=` operator.

```
select 
    id 
from job_post
where 
    date(created_at) = '2021-03-01';
```

As @forpas pointed out above query will not work since the datetime format is not ok. You can first extract the first 10 character from that string then convert it into date type.

```
select 
        id 
    from job_post
    where 
        date(substr(created_at,1,10)) = '2021-03-01';
```

Comment: `date(created_at)` will return `null` because `created_at` does not have the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=65c3dd379afa55976197805764a623b2

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have revised my answer. *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4145bc3ae4bd9b08179c5de5cc1ec7cd)*

Comment: If you use `substr()` to get the date part then there is no need for `date()`. A simple `where substr(created_at,1,10) = '2021-03-01'` is fine. But the problem that has to be addressed here is the format of timestamps the OP uses. This must be changed.

Comment: I do agree with you. It should be changed if possible.

Comment: i will try this, thanks, sorry late reply